# How can I calculate gasPrice on Multi EVM chains?

Tags: ethers.js, gas-estimate

*While calling the function in the contract in different EVM chains, I get gas error in other chains. How can I fix this?*

```
// File: Vault.sol
contract Vault {

function doSometing(string memory message,  uint256 age) public { 
   // some logic
 }

}
```

Polygon, phantom, arbitrum and other chains I apply the same model interacting with smart contracts. My smart contract calls for all of them are as follows

```js
// File: call.js

const gasPrice = ethers.utils.parseUnits('25', 'gwei');

await contract.doSometing('this is example message', 50, {
            gasLimit: 100000,
            gasPrice: gasPrice
})
```

I want to execute gasPrice and gasLimit by adding slightly more than the network's current amount of gas when calling a function in a smart contract

#### Update 02.02.2024

chatGPT's recommendation. I want to know if this is a good way

```js
const currentGasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();
const increasedGasPrice = currentGasPrice.mul(120).div(100);

await contract.doSometing('this is example message', 50,{
    gasLimit: 100000,
    gasPrice: increasedGasPrice
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For "ethers": "^6.10.0"

```
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(YOUR_URL_RPC);
var gasFee = (await provider.getFeeData()).gasPrice;
var gasLimit = contract.doSometing('this is example message', 50).estimateGas(param1, param2);
```

Comment: I actually work with multiple chains.
I asked ChatGPT and it gave me this answer. (See update)